# How to import an external library in Android?

Tags: android, slider, import-libraries

I am attempting to integrate a library into my Android app. It's the [SlideMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library.

My problem is I can't find simple enough instructions to help a beginner through this.

There is a great looking [tutorial](http://www.michenux.net/android-sliding-menu-part-1-657.html) but there is no detail on how to actually install the library i:e what is the step-by-step process. I'm really lost on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have downloaded the library?

- If not, download it and extract the actual library project folder. (it just looks like any other Android project folder you might have seen)
- Import it into your Eclipse workspace.  (it will then just look like any other project in your workspace explorer)
- Then right-click on your project and go to properties.
- Select "Android" and press the "Add" Button on the bottom of the window.
- Select your    desired library.
- Thats it.

Comment: Thank you Phil. Simple and straight forward. Easier than I thought. Much appreciated